# LinearLayout space between 2 buttons

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

this is my linearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ANNULLA"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="#87a914"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="SALVA"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="#87a914"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this the result:
[image]
I would like to have a **space between the button "SALVA" and the button "ANNULLA"**
i mean something like that:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add this attribute in the second button

```
android:layout_marginLeft="xdp"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add an empty `View` in between them with a suitable `weight`

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height-"wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".2"/>  // change this to what works for you
```

your `width` for the `Buttons` should be "0dp" when using `layout_weight`

Answer (score 1):

My favourite way is to add invisible view between buttons, something like this:

`<View
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible" />`